# create Polygon from point collection with NetTopologySuite

Tags: .net, vb.net, nettopologysuite

What is the best way to create a polygon from list of point?

I have an array of points, if points are at least 3 I would like to join to create a polygon

```
Dim ClickedPoint As New NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(coordinates)
ClickedPointArray.Add(ClickedPoint)

if   ClickedPointArray.Count > 2 then

   Polygonizer = New Polygonizer()
   Polygonizer.Add(ClickedPointArray)

end if        

return Polygonizer.GetPolygons
```

I think I'm very far from solution.
Could you help me?

Comment: Like this? ` var сoordinates = new List<NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate>();
                    var polygon = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon(new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.LinearRing(сoordinates.ToArray()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Polygon with an array of coordinates using GeometryFactory like this:

```
Dim coordinatesArray as Coordinate[] = YourMethodToGetCoordinates
Dim geomFactory As New GeometryFactory
Dim poly As geomFactory.CreatePolygon(coordinatesArray) //this returns an IPolygon that you can cast to Polygon
```

Comment: (Maybe it's already late to answer this, but I was looking for the same(in C#) and when I solved it I thought answering this could be useful for the next one visiting)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the C#

> ```
>     Coordinate[] imageOutlineCoordinates = new Coordinate[] 
>     {
>         new Coordinate(1, 1),
>         new Coordinate(2, 1),
>         new Coordinate(2, 2),
>         new Coordinate(1, 1)
>     };
>     GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
>     Polygon poly = geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(imageOutlineCoordinates);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for c# using nettopologysuite (https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite)

```
Polygon GetGeometry(Coordinate[] coordinates)
        {
            var geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
            var polygon = new Polygon(new LinearRing(coordinates), geometryFactory);
            return polygon;
        }
```

Note: here 4326 is srid of coordinate system. Without this geometry operations dont give correct results

--------------------------------- Usage of above method

```
var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();


 for (var index = 0; index < doubleList.Count; index = index + 2)
    {
      var coordinate = new Coordinate(doubleList[index], doubleList[index + 1]);
        coordinates.Add(coordinate);
    }   


   coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(points[0], points[1]));
    
   GetGeometry(coordinates.ToArray())
```